# How use RxJs in thingsboard widgets

Tags: thingsboard

does anyone know how to use RxJs in widgets? create streams for example. the only thing that found it `self.ctx.rxjs.of()`. but there is no use. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Static widget](https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/ui/widget-library/#static) with any custom HTML, CSS and external JS libs